# Remove a Wrap Panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to remove a Wrap Panel from c# code. The Wrap Panel is present inside a Canvas.  The code snippet are as follows

```
this.CanvasName.Children.Remove(WrapPanelName);
```

However, The Wrap Panel still appears in the Window? Any help!

**Edited:**
This code works,

```
               int childCount = WrapPanelName.Children.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
                {
                    ///Remove the old.
                    WrapPanelName.Children.RemoveAt(0);
                }
```

Comment: Don't manipulate the visual tree in procedural code. Learn to use WPF properly by defining your UI in XAML and using proper DataBinding to show data on it.

Comment: Could you explain more why you need to delete the wrapPanel, and if is it possible to manipulate it from Xaml

Comment: @moez Because, dynamically, I need to replace the wrap panel with another image based upon some condition(via code)

Comment: You can do it dynamically with XAML. And it is the right way to do it in XAML.

Answer (score 3):

Try that code it works with me :

## Xaml

```
<Canvas Name="YourCanavasName">
    <WrapPanel  Name="YourWrapName" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="31" Width="63" Height="41" Fill="Blue"  />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="130" Canvas.Top="79" Width="58" Height="58" Fill="Blue"  />
    </WrapPanel>
</Canvas>
```

## Code Behind

```
YourCanavasName.Children.Remove(YourWrapName);
```

Comment: Did you try it or not